# fluidcontent as container does not render

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm trying to setup a small Website based von TYPO3 6.2 with flux and fluid Templating Engine.
I use:
fluid: 6.2
flux: 7.2.1
fluidpages 3.2.3
fluidcontent 4.2.2
fluidcontent_core: 1.1.3
vhs: 2.3.3
builder: 0.18.0

I have used the builder for a provider extension and I have managed to make page templates and also content templates.
But when I try to use a content element as content container it will not be rendered.

I have read similar articles here and also the documentation but I can't find a solution.

The static TS of fluidcontent_core is included.

I have also copied the line

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['contentRenderingTemplates'] = array('fluidcontentcore/Configuration/TypoScript/');
```

in AdditionalConfiguration.

Following is my minimal Conatinertemplate:

```
div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
 xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers">

<f:layout name="Content" />

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="btContainer" label="UpContainer" options="{group: 'stth'}">

    </flux:form>
    <flux:grid>
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column name="Col2" label="Inhalte" />
        </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">
    <!-- If you wish, place custom backend preview content here -->


</f:section>
<f:section name="Main">
        <div class="container addedClass">
            <f:comment><flux:content.render area="Col2" /></f:comment>
            <v:content.render column="Col2"  />
        </div>
</f:section>
```

I have tried to render content with v:content.render or flux:content.render but there is no output. 
I get only an empty

```
  <div class="container addedclass"> </div>
```

In the Backend I see the Container, labeled "Inhalte" and I can add Content. (Content is Standard CE like Text or header)

Can someone please give me a hint, what I can do next.

Thank you in advance
st

**Update 1.7.2015**

I have set up a new TYPO3 6.2 und used the preconfigured 'site kickstarter'.
As I added the AdditionalConfiguration.php I saw there where 2 lines to copy:

```
    // fluidcontent_core
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['contentRenderingTemplates'] =   array('fluidcontentcore/Configuration/TypoScript/');
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['activateContentAdapter'] = 0;
```

The second one is new to me.

Then I copied my Container-template in the my Provider extension: and YES - it works.

I tried to use the second line of AdditionalConfiguration in my original TYPO3 instance -- but there it does not work. So I am not shure if this was the solution. Perhaps someone has more insight?

Again: Thank you for your help.

Comment: colPos is not required on flux:grid.column, but this might give a conflict.  What do you see in the database ? Also, you use fluidcontent_core. I assume that you have inserted the ts for fluidcontent_core and disabled css_styled_content? (even uninstall css_styled_content ?)

Comment: Yes, I had inserted TS for  fluidcontent_core in Main TS-Template -> Edit whole template record -> Includes
I have not installed css_styled_content; I even deleted the line from LocalConfiguration.php and tested again -> same effect.
I can not see that I am using colPos -- can you please tell me where I use it?
Database:
I am not shure in which table I should search:
I have now put a regular Text CE in my container "Inhalte";
the Text can be found in tt_content but not in CF_fluidcontent. Is this correct?

Comment: cf_ is cache tables    look in tt_content (because that is what it is)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some mistake in your code:

Your `<flux:grid>` code is outside of `<flux:form>` It should be inside. Please check entire code below:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xmlns:flux="http://fedext.net/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
         xmlns:v="http://fedext.net/ns/vhs/ViewHelpers" 
         xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">

         <f:layout name="Content" />
         <f:section name="Configuration">
            <flux:form id="btContainer" label="UpContainer" options="{group: 'Custom elements'}">
                <flux:grid>
                    <flux:grid.row>
                        <flux:grid.column name="Col2" style="width: 100%" label="Inhalte" ></flux:grid.column>
                    </flux:grid.row>
                </flux:grid>
            </flux:form>
        </f:section>

        <f:section name="Preview">
            <flux:widget.grid />
        </f:section>

        <f:section name="Main">
                <div class="container addedClass">
                    <flux:content.render render="1" area="Col2" />
                </div>
        </f:section>

</div>
```

Comment: I put '<flux:grid>' inside '<flux:form>', but that does not solve the problem. I also tried with 'render=1' but nothing happens. I wonder if there is a better way of debugging -- a kind of step by step testing? The fact that I can see 'div class="container addedClass" in the FE says that at least the Main section is rendered, but not the content of '<flux:content ..>'